# Add serialization group to vendor's class property

Tags: api, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I'm using [doctrine2-spatial](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial) in [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/).

For the `CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\AbstractPoint` class, I need to add a [serialization group](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization-groups-and-relations) for `$x` and `$y` properties.

What would be the best way to accomplish this without altering the vendor?

Answer (score -1):

In the serializer documentation, they provide example in comment to use yml and xml) mapping for serialization group.
This way you can add some serialization group pointing to the vendor entity without having to use the annotation in the vendor classes

```
$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new YamlFileLoader('/path/to/your/definition.yml'));
```

Comment: I'm reading about it and I'm not sure where to put this. I'm using annotations and ideally my issue should be resolved via an AppBundle of my own that takes into account some groups defined in another Bundle. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: like this blog entry: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups. I think I understand the code, just don't know where to put it

Comment: Honestly I don't know I never used it, i just saw it in the documentation. It should be defined by a service with the right tag I guess. Sorry